# Enforcing a structure in a nn.Parameter (matrix) parameter in Pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, parameters, pytorch

In the PyTorch library it is possible to define a neural network parameter `nn.Parameter` with some initial value, e.g.,

```
some_param = nn.Parameter(data=torch.rand(4,4))
```

In my case, I want to enforce some structure on this parameter. Think of for example a strictly lower triangular form (in the case of a matrix parameter), hence `some_param` is of the form:

```
[ 0   0   0   0 ]
[a21  0   0   0 ]
[a31 a32  0   0 ]
[a41 a42 a43  0 ]
```

However, if I initialize the parameter with

```
some_param = nn.Parameter(data=torch.tril(torch.rand(4,4),-1))
```

then the zeros on and above the diagonal can get non-zero during training... How can I ensure that this parameter retains its structure during training?

Comment: Did you look into PyTorch pruning (essentially parameter masking)?

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly store only 6 parameters and then construct the full matrix on-the-fly:

```py
class StructuredParameter(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, ...):
    self.explicit_p = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(6,))
    self.tril_ind = torch.tril_indice(4, 4, -1)

  def forward(self, ...):
    # before using some_param - create it
    some_param = torch.zeros(4, 4)
    some_params[self.tril_ind] = self.explicit_p

    # use some_param ...
```